# When using radio button,I'm tring to hide div, the checkbox list[control itself] is not displayed

Tags: asp.net, checkboxlist

script:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#Custom').hide('fast'); 
          $('#rbtnEntire').click(function () {
             $('#Custom').hide('fast');
            $('#Entire').show('fast');
            });

          $('#rbtnCustom').click(function () {
            $('#Entire').hide('fast');
            $('#Custom').show('fast');
           });
      });

    function showdiv() {
        document.getElementById("divChkList").style.display = "block";
     }
```

aspx file:

```
<div style="height:700; width:500;">
<div id="select scan type">
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnEntire" runat="server" Text="Entire" 
        GroupName="s1"/>
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnCustom" runat="server" Text="Custom" 
        GroupName="s1"/>
</div>
<div id="Entire" style="float:left; height:1000; width:1000; border: solid 1px;  margin-left:5px;">
    Entire<br />
    <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ShowCheckBoxes="All" ShowLines="True" ExpandDepth="2">
     <Nodes>
     <asp:TreeNode Text="Entire">
          <asp:TreeNode Text="VM">
            <asp:TreeNode Text="MBS1">   
        </asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="PF1"></asp:TreeNode>
        </asp:TreeNode>


        <asp:TreeNode Text="VM1">
        <asp:TreeNode Text="MBS2"></asp:TreeNode>
        <asp:TreeNode Text="PF2"></asp:TreeNode>
        </asp:TreeNode>

    </asp:TreeNode>
    </Nodes>
    </asp:TreeView>
        <p>
    <asp:Button ID="btnCreateXML" runat="server" onclick="btnCreateXML_Click" 
        Text="Create XML" />
   <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
   </p></div>
   <div id="Custom" style="float:left; height:1000; width:2000; border: solid 1px; margin-left:10px;">

    Custom <br />
    <div id="Manual" style="border:solid 1px; float:left;">
        Manual Scan Controls
    </div>

    <div id="Multiple" style="border:solid 1px; float:left;">
    Multiple Scan Controls
        <table>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" style="width: 165px">  
                          <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phDDLCHK" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                          <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Get Checked" OnClick="btn_Click" />
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                          <asp:Label ID="lblSelectedItem" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
              </tr>
        </table>
     </div>
     <asp:HiddenField ID="hidList" runat="server" />
    </div>
   <br />
   </div>
```

code behind:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {


    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        initialiseCheckBoxList();
        rbtnEntire.Checked = true;
        try
        {
            TreeView1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript: OnTreeClick();");
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            Response.Write("Error Occured While onTreeClick");
        }
    }
}
  public void initialiseCheckBoxList()
  {

   CheckBoxList chkBxLst = new CheckBoxList();
   chkBxLst.ID = "chkLstItem";
    chkBxLst.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "showdiv()");
    DataTable dtListItem = GetListItem();
    int rowNo = dtListItem.Rows.Count;
    string lstValue = string.Empty;
    string lstID = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowNo - 1; i++)
    {
        lstValue = dtListItem.Rows[i]["Value"].ToString();
        lstID = dtListItem.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();
        chkBxLst.Items.Add(lstValue);
    }
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl div = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div.ID = "divChkList";
    div.Controls.Add(chkBxLst);
    div.Style.Add("border", "black 1px solid");
    div.Style.Add("width", "160px");
    div.Style.Add("height", "130px");
    div.Style.Add("overflow", "AUTO");
    div.Style.Add("display", "block");


   }//end of initialiseCheckBoxList()
  protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    string x=string.Empty;
    string strSelectedItem = "Selected Items ";
    CheckBoxList chk = (CheckBoxList)phDDLCHK.FindControl("chkLstItem");    // phDDLCHK is placeholder's ID

    for (int i = 0; i < chk.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (chk.Items[i].Selected)
        {
            if (strSelectedItem.Length == 0)
            {
                       strSelectedItem = strSelectedItem + ":" + chk.Items[i].Text;

            }
            else
            {
                strSelectedItem = strSelectedItem + ":" + chk.Items[i].Text;
                                }
        }
    }
           lblSelectedItem.Text =strSelectedItem;
  }

  public DataTable GetListItem()  
  {
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

    for (int icnt = 0; icnt < 10; icnt++)
    {
        table.Rows.Add(icnt, "ListItem"+":"+icnt);
    }
    return table;
}
```

Problem: When i Select radio button rbtnCustom, It should display div Custom along with the CheckboxList control,which is not happening. When I do not hide div,it is displayed. What can be done to display checkboxList control?
Here is my code, Can any one let me know where I went wrong?
Any help would be appriciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason some of your Javascript isn't working is because you are using the **server** ID in the client side (Javascript) code.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnCustom" runat="server" Text="Custom" 
        GroupName="s1"/>
```

Since the above control is set to `runat="server"` the ID attribute is setting a sever side control ID, the client ID will be generated. If you don't need access to this control on the server, it might be easier to simply use a 'input' element instead of an asp.net control. The other option would be to set the `ClientIDMode="Static"` so the client ID is the same as the server ID.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnCustom" runat="server" Text="Custom" ClientIDMode="Static"
            GroupName="s1"/>
```

Use this for any control if you are not setting the ID in the code behind and if you are using the ID in client side Javascript.

EDIT: You are also missing `phDDLCHK.Controls.Add(div);` at the end of your `initialiseCheckBoxList` method.

You are also not providing what javascript "OnTreeClick();" is. It is referenced in the code behind. From what I can tell you are only populating the contents of the custom checkboxlist once on the initialiseCheckBoxList.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! I tried your suggestions, but in both cases the checkboxlist is not displayed. Is there is any Problem,cause I'm creating the checkboxlist in code behind or any wrong property I have set?

Comment: With my code changes on both Radio button controls, the show and hide works. I am including all your code behind, but removing the 'OnClick' event from 'btnCreateXML' as you have not included it. But this should not effect your radio buttons showing and hiding client side

Comment: @user1746468 make sure you are adding ClientIDMode="Static" to both 'rbtnEntire' and 'rbtnCustom'

Comment: K Hide & show do work. But the Problem is after the hide & show the **control checkboxlist is not getting displayed, which is placed in the div Custom**

Comment: Updated. You are not adding the controls to phDDLCHK

Comment: **Thanks!** Now I have added it! But still same problem exits of checkboxlist control. When i do set custom.show() in script,the control is displayed, but after clicking on radio button & hide & show, The control disappers

Comment: @user1746468 'The control disappers' The checkboxlist? I can click 'Entire' and 'Custom' radio buttons back and forth and they seem to show and hide without error. Unless I am misunderstanding something...

Comment: @user1746468 You are missing 'showdiv()' from the code provided with does cause problems with what I am testing.

Comment: I have added the showdiv(), & problem is not while switching, but while swtiching the contents of div custom[checkboxlist] not getting displayed  **Thanks for your answers.making me aware of small issues also**

Answer (score 0):

### How to use asp checkbox control as RadioButton

**First we create a script like this:**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function check(sender) {
        var chkBox;
        var i;
        var j;
        for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
                if (i != j) {
                    if (sender.id == "ck" + i) {
                        chkBox = document.getElementById("ck" + j);
                    }
                    else {
                        chkBox = document.getElementById("ck" + i);
                    }
                    if (sender.checked) {
                        if (chkBox.checked) {
                            chkBox.checked = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 </script>
```

**Now we use following code for our ASP CheckBox controls**

```
    <div>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="ck1" runat="server" Text="P1" onclick="check(this)"/>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="ck2" runat="server" Text="P2" onclick="check(this)"/>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="ck3" runat="server" Text="P3" onclick="check(this)"/>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="ck4" runat="server" Text="P4" onclick="check(this)"/>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="ck5" runat="server" Text="P5" onclick="check(this)"/>
   </div>
```

**Thank you...**